# Why isn't the close() method closing the window I created?

Tags: javascript

I'm facing no errors but the function `windowClose()` doesn't work when I click on 'close window' button, why?

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="open window" onclick="windowOpen()">
    <input type="button" value="close window" onclick="windowClose()">
    <script src="window.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```js
let myWindow;

function windowOpen(){
    myWindow = window.open("https://google.com", "_blank");
}

function windowClose(){
    myWindow.close();
}
```

I was expecting that the new window would close when I click on the 'close window' button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work in general. However, it won't work with sites like `www.google.com`, which use a more restrictive cross-origin opener policy.

Specifically, they send the following header:

```
Cross-origin-owner-policy: same-origin-allow-popups
```

The [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#the-coop-headers) says:

> This forces the creation of a new top-level browsing context for the document, unless its predecessor specified the same cross-origin opener policy and they are same origin.

Since it's in a different browsing context, the window can't be closed from the original page.

Comment: I'm glad you saw the question. How did I forget about COOP? :-D

Comment: Luckily I saw a question a month or two ago where someone was having a different problem with a popup window, and it was because they used google in their test.